# Modifying XSL in xsltlistviewwebpart to render SharePoint 2010 ListItems as <ul> and <li> instead of <Table><tr><td>

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I am trying to achieve what is mentioned in the title, but having trouble, need help. I am modifying the following templates

```
1. <xsl:template name="View_Default_RootTemplate" mode="RootTemplate" match="View" ddwrt:dvt_mode="root" ddwrt:ghost="hide">

2. <xsl:template match="View" mode="full" ddwrt:ghost="hide">

3. <xsl:template mode="Item" match="Row" ddwrt:ghost="hide">
```

Q-1 Should i be modifying any other templates?

Desired end result - To render a recursive view and each list item as `<li>listitem...</li> surrounded by a top level <ul>`

Q-2 when i change the  elements to `<ul> and <tr> to <li>` the final page is still rendered with tables which i don't see in the templates and the `<ul> & <li>` changes are inserted into some unknown `<td>`, the questions are

a. What is the right way to do this?

b. what template is applied in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a simple enough solution so I would suggest writing a separate XSLT stylesheet rather than trying to customise the thousands of lines that are in a standard stylesheet.  There is a 3-part tutorial on my [blog](http://paylord.wordpress.com) which should help with the basics but essentially you need the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />
 <ul>
 <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
  <xsl:call-template name="RowView" />
 </xsl:for-each>
 </ul>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="RowView">
 <li>
  <xsl:value-of select="@ColumnName" />
 </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks, great blog Dave, but by this method i have to sacrifice the recursive folders view.

Comment: Change the view on your web part - under Folders set to Show All Items Without Folders.